# python list n files then next n files in a directory and Map it to a mapper function

Tags: python, mapreduce, out-of-memory

I have a directory in which I have around hundred thousands of text files.
Python code creates a list of names of this files,

```
listoffiles = os.listdir(directory)
```

I break this `listoffiles` with `lol` function in **64** parts

```
lol = lambda lst, sz: [lst[i:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(lst), sz)]
partitioned_listoffiles = lol(listoffiles, 64)
```

Then I pool it to **2** processes

```
pool = Pool(processes=2,)
single_count_tuples = pool.map(Map, partitioned_listoffiles)
```

In `Map` function I read those files and do further processing

My problem is this code works fine if I do it for small folder with thousands of files. Large directories it runs out of memory. How should I solve this issue. Can I read first n files and then next n files and create `listoffiles` and process this steps in for loop.

Comment: is `Pool()` constructor protected by `if __name__=="__main__"` condition?

Comment: Yes `Pool()` constructor is within `__name__=="__main__"` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the directory is very very large then you could use [`scandir()`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) instead of `os.listdir()`. But it is unlikely that `os.listdir()` causes `MemoryError` therefore the issue is in the other two places:

1. Use a generator expression instead of list comprehension:

   ```
   chunks = (lst[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n))
   ```
2. Use `pool.imap` or `pool.imap_unordered` instead of `pool.map()`:

   ```
   for result in pool.imap_unordered(Map, chunks):
       pass
   ```

Or better:

```
files = os.listdir(directory)
for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_file, files, chunksize=100):
    pass
```

Comment: I get Segmentation Fault. Good answer, I need to try it out.

Comment: @Wazzzy: are you telling me that if you run: `python -c"import os; os.listdir('your dir here')"` it causes MemoryError?

Comment: I am getting Segmentation Fault Sir so don't know exactly what is causing the Error...

Comment: @Wazzzy: what happens if you run the command from my previous comment?

Comment: @Wazzzy: what happens if `process_file` function does nothing: `def process_file(filename): return filename`? Do you get segfault in that case? Create a [*minimal* complete code example that shows the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar problem, where I was required to verify a certain number of files are in a specific folder. The problem was that the folder may contain up to 20 million very small files.
From what I've learned, there is no possibility to limit pythons `listdir` to a certain amount of items.

My `listdir` takes quite a while to list the directory and a lot of RAM but manages to run on a VM with 4GB RAM..

You may want to try using `glob` instead, which might keep the file list smaller, depending on your requirements.

```
import glob
print glob.glob("/tmp/*.txt")
```

Comment: For the answer but all are `.txt` files in my directory. Do you mean to say `glob` will be better than `listdir` in terms of memory.

Comment: unfortunately `glob` will only reduce the memory consumption if there are multiple file types in the directory and you'd require only specific ones.

Comment: That is not the case with me. I have same file types. Cant I list only first n files then next n and so on.

Comment: According to my research there is no possibility of doing this in python.. yet.